# Price of in-app billing subscription according to usage?

Tags: google-play, in-app-billing

Does Google Play allow for a "pay for what you use" type of subscription in in-app billing, or does the price have to be fixed?
Thanks!

Comment: create a new subsription id in google play store with required price and use app logic to pickup id based on price https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

Comment: Fixed spelling and grammar.

Comment: Hey @Amod, can you specify this? I can't quite follow your short instructions.